# Total generalized variance for Box-Cox transformed components

Tags: variance, data-transformation, model-selection, aggregation, boxcox-transformation

I have a couple Gaussian mixture models where each component comes from (component-wise) Box-Cox transformed data. These models do not describe the same data: the individual components are selected based on certain consistency criteria (irrelevant to this question). Because these data points represent measurements, I would like to choose the "most precise" model, which I define as having the least total variance.

The caveat is that **the (total) variance should be understood in terms of the physically measured, untransformed space** – after all, that's exactly why the "precision" matters. **But I can't/don't just want to use the variances of the raw data components as-is,** because they come from heavily skewed, asymmetric distributions, so the arithmetic mean and variance are not the most appropriate descriptions of the components. That's why I'm performing a Box-Cox transformation in the first place.

So I'm thinking of minimizing variance in the Box-Cox transformed space, which I'm calling the generalized variance hereafter. For example, in the special case where the components are perfectly log-normally distributed and the Box-Cox transform is therefore just the natural logarithm, the generalized variance just reduces to the log of the geometric variance, and I'd be minimizing the total variance

$$
\mathbb{V}_{total} := \sum_i{\mathbb{V}[\ln(x_{i,\cdot})]]}
$$

which has units 1 (as opposed to having the same units as the measurements squared). However, this quantity seems to heavily depend on the particular ML estimate of the $\lambda$ parameter of the Box-Cox transform, and so it might not be the best idea to minimize.

So another idea would be to minimize some aggregation of the **inverse-transformed** generalized variances (in the original raw measurement space), which would be, in the log-normal case:

$$
\mathbb{V}_{total} := \mathrm{F}(e^{\mathbb{V}[\ln(x_{i,\cdot}]])})
$$
where $F$ is some appropriately-defined aggregation function analogous to summation in the transformed space. I'm pretty sure that's the product when all components are log-normally distributed. But the problem is I don't know how to derive an appropriate aggregation function in the case where the estimated $\lambda_i$ are different for each component.

My questions are:

1. Does it make sense to go with my first idea and minimize the total variance in the Box-Cox transformed space if I want to find the least spread-out components in the original space?
2. If it doesn't, and I go with the second idea of aggregating variances in the untransformed space, what aggregation function do I need if I want to correctly handle different parameters for different components?

Comment: There is no valid way to compare the variance of one nonlinearly transformed variable to that of another.  That fact makes it difficult or impossible to understand what you are doing and what you want to accomplish.  Could you back up a little and reframe your question in terms of more concrete, relevant information?

Comment: @whuber "There is no valid way to compare the variance of one nonlinearly transformed variable to that of another." – I don't think that's the case. We are talking about invertible transformations, after all. But let's tackle this very piece first, then. Let e.g. $Y = \mathrm{BoxCox}(X; \lambda)$ s.t. Y is normally distributed. Are you saying that there is no sensible measure of scale for X, given the variance or standard deviation computed for Y? The existence of such objects as the geometric standard deviation seems to contradict your point.

Comment: @whuber Thinking about it, maybe I didn't express myself clearly enough. I am not interested in comparing the variances of the *transformed* variables. Since the raw untransformed data are physically meaningful measurements, I need to compare which of them is spread out more in the untransformed space. However, I feel that simply computing the variance of the raw data doesn't really capture that notion due to their potentially heavily skewed distribution.

Comment: You seem to be saying, in the same breath, that you want to compute the spread in the original data but you don't believe you want to do that!  That makes it difficult to determine what you really do need to accomplish.

Comment: @whuber I want a measure of spread in the original data that takes into account the shape of the distribution. The plain old variance is not meaningful if the distributions are heavily skewed.

Comment: That's fair; but "account for the shape of the distribution" is vague and leads to a huge variety of possible solutions.  One standard method is to assume the distribution belongs to a family of possible distributions parameterized by some numbers and that one of those numbers is the intended quantitative expression of the spread.

Comment: @whuber Fair enough. After thinking more about the points you raised, I did a bit more domain-specific research. It turns out the data I want to model empirically follows a log-normal distribution most of the time anyway. Also, even in theory, they are always positive. So I decided to simplify the model and just log-transform everything, without fitting a power transform.